# Scanner vs FileInputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, io

```
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(new File("target.txt"));
```

and

```
FileInputStream d = new FileInputStream("target.txt");
```

What is the difference between `Scanner.nextByte()` and `FileInputStream.read()` ?

I am trying to understand it because when i read bytes (one by one) from a file with simple text with the `FileInputStream` it works fine. But when iam using `Scanner` the `scanner.nextByte()` doesn't return anything?

Why is that?

Comment: Did you use a delimiter on your Scanner, like `scanner.useDelimiter(REGEX_INPUT_BOUNDARY_BEGINNING).next()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scanner.nextByte() will read the next token and if it can be evaluated as a byte then return it while FileInoutStream.read() will return each byte of a file. Consider this example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO {
  public static void scanner() throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Reading with the Scanner Class:");
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(new File("target.txt"));
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
      try {
        System.out.println("A Byte:"+scanner.nextByte());
      } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Not a byte:"+scanner.next());
      }
    }
    scanner.close();
  }

  public static void stream() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Reading with the FileInputStream Class:");
    FileInputStream d = new FileInputStream("target.txt");
    int b = -1;
    while((b = d.read()) != -1) {
      System.out.print((byte)b+" ");
    }
    d.close();
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String...args) throws IOException {
    scanner();
    stream();
  }
}
```

With this as the contents of `target.txt`:

```
Next up is a byte:
6
Wasn't that fun?
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Reading with the Scanner Class:
Not a byte:Next
Not a byte:up
Not a byte:is
Not a byte:a
Not a byte:byte:
A Byte:6
Not a byte:Wasn't
Not a byte:that
Not a byte:fun?
Reading with the FileInputStream Class:
78 101 120 116 32 117 112 32 105 115 32 97 32 98 121 116 101 58 10 54 10 87 97 115 110 39 116 32 116 104 97 116 32 102 117 110 63
```

Answer (score 4):

These classes are actually doing very different things.

A `FileInputStream` is actually reading raw bytes from the input file, whereas `Scanner` is parsing the file as whitespace-separated tokens, and trying the convert each token into the requested type when you ask for it.

If, for instance, your input file looks like this:

```
1
```

`FileInputStream.read()` will evaluate the `1` as a byte, and return its value: `49`.
`Scanner.nextByte()` will read the `1` and try to evaluate it as an integer regular expression of radix 10, and give you: `1`.

If, on the other hand, your input file contains

```
a
```

Then `FileInputStream.read()` will evaluate the `a` as a byte, and return its value: `97`.
`Scanner.nextByte()` will read the `a` and try to evaluate it as an integer regular expression of radix 10, and throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

Comment: Sooo in other words, Scanner.nextByte() reads only integers in a file right?

Answer (score 1):

The `Scanner.nextByte()` is not the same as `FileInputStream.read().`

The `nextByte()` method scans the next token of the input as a byte. This method will throw **InputMismatchException** if the next token cannot be translated into a valid byte value as described below. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

If the next token matches the `Integer` regular expression defined above then the token is converted into a byte value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting string to `Byte.parseByte` with the specified radix.

i.e. The `nextByte()` method try to match a textual representation of a number to store it in as a byte value.

On the other side, `FileInputStream.read()` will read a byte of data from the input stream.

References : [FileInputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) [Scanner.nextByte()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextByte%28%29) [Scanner.nextByte(int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextByte%28int%29)