# the logic behind the diffrerence between fileInputStream and Scanner classes

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream

I'm trying to understand the difference between `Scanner.nextByte()` and `FileInputStream.read()`. I read similar topics, but I didn't find the answer of my question. A similar question is asked in the topic : [Scanner vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943067/scanner-vs-fileinputstream)

***Let me say what I understand :***

Say that a `.txt` file includes

```
1
```

Then,
`FileInputStream.read()` will return 49

`Scanner.nextByte()` will return 1

If `.txt` file includes

```
a
```

`FileInputStream.read()` will return 97.

`Scanner.nextByte()` will throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

In the answers which I gave the link, it said that:

> `FileInputStream.read()` will evaluate the 1 as a byte, and return its
>   value: 49.  `Scanner.nextByte()` will read the 1 and try to evaluate
>   it as an integer regular expression of radix 10, and give you: 1.
>
> `FileInputStream.read()` will evaluate the a as a byte, and return its
>   value: 97.  `Scanner.nextByte()` will read the a and try to evaluate
>   it as an integer regular expression  of radix 10, and throw a
>   `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

But I didn't understand what they mean actually. Can you explain these words in simple words with more clear examples? I looked at ASCII table, character 1 corresponds to 49. The reason of `FileInputStream.read()` return 49 is because of that?

I'm totaly confused. Please explain me in simple words.

Comment: *"FileInputStream.read() will throw a java.util.InputMismatchException."* and later ... *"Scanner.nextByte() will [..] throw a java.util.InputMismatchException"* ... can you please re-check your question?

Comment: You are saying opposite things? First you say fileInputSream.read() would throw error, then you its Scanner.nextByte() that throws the error . Would advice you fix that. I am guessing its the Scanner that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files contain bytes. FileInputStream reads these bytes. So if a file contains one byte whose value is 49, stream.read() will return 49. If the file contains two identical bytes 49, calling read() twice will return 49, then 49.

Characters like 'a', '1' or 'Z' can be stored in files. To be stored in files, they first have to be transformed into bytes, because that's what files contain. There are various ways (called "character encodings") to transform characters to bytes. Some of them (like ASCII, ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8) transform the character '1' into the byte 49.

Scanner reads characters from a file. So it transforms the bytes in the file to characters (using the character encoding, but in the other direction: from bytes to characters). Some sequences of characters form decimal numbers, like for example '123', '-5265', or '1'. Some don't, like 'abc'.

When you call `nextByte()` on a Scanner, you ask the scanner to read the next sequence of characters (until the next white space or until the end of the file if there is no whitespace), then to check if this sequence of characters represents a valid decimal number, and to check that this decimal number fits into a byte (i.e. be a number between -128 and 127). If it is, the sequence of characters is parsed as a decimal number, stored int a byte, and returned.

So if the file contains the byte 49 twice, the sequence of characters read and parsed by nextByte() would be '11', which would be transformed into the byte 11.

Comment: You mean that, FileInputStream reads from binary files, Scanner reads from text files. If my file is sample.txt, FileInputStream reads from the binary file of sample.txt, Scanner reads directly from sample.txt. Right?

Comment: No. All files are binary files. They all contain bytes. Some happen to contain bytes that represent characters in a given character encoding. And they are, conventionally, called "text files". When using a Scanner, the Scanner uses a character encoding to first transform sequences of bytes into sequences of characters, and then parse these sequences of characters into numbers.

Comment: OK for scanner. However, FileInputStream reads raw bytes, and transforms the byte value to int, and return that int value, right?

Comment: In addition, sample.txt file contains 1 . Thus binary format actually contains 49. Scanner.read() reads 49 from binary file. Then it converts binary value 49 to character 1.Thus scanner.read() returns character, right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Scanner returns 1 because it's supposed to interpret characters as numbers. Because if I ask you to edit a file and enter the number 12, you'll type the characters '1' and '2', and the text editor will write the bytes 49 and 50 in the file. You won't enter the binary value 12, because a keyboard doesn't allow doing that. So, if I want to read the number 12 from this file, I'll have to read the characters 1 and 2 from the file, and parse the string "12" as a number. That's what Scanner allows doing.